# PDO ODBC to IBM DB2 on iSeries causes segfault on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, pdo, db2, unixodbc, db2-400

we try to connect from a Unix System (Ubuntu) to a DB2 on iSeries with PDO ODBC.
So far everything fine. If we get NULL-valus within a result array this causes to a segfault.

Here some test code to reproduce the segfault:

```
$pdo_dsn = "odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC DRIVER};SYSTEM=***";
$pdo_username = "***";
$pdo_password = "***";
$pdo_dbh = new PDO(
    $pdo_dsn, 
    $pdo_username, 
    $pdo_password,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
$pdo_query = "SET SCHEMA [SCHEMANAME]";
$pdo_params = array();
$pdo_stmt = $pdo_dbh->prepare($pdo_query);
$pdo_stmt_result = $pdo_stmt->execute($pdo_params);
$pdo_query = "SELECT * FROM [FIRSTTABLE] LEFT JOIN [OTHERTABLE] ON (1=2)";
$pdo_params = array();
$pdo_stmt = $pdo_dbh->prepare($pdo_query);
$pdo_stmt_result = $pdo_stmt->execute($pdo_params);
$pdo_result = $pdo_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The last line causes the segfault!

```
php5[26525]: segfault at 2035000 ip 00007f8bf21f18d3 sp 00007fff78f1d3d8 error 6 in libc-2.15.so[7f8bf20a8000+1b5000]
```

What we did to fix:

1. Adding the following PDO-Attribute with no effect:

   1. PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_TO_STRING
2. Activate the unixodbc.log and checked it. Query was successfull executed:

   1. Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
3. Insert IFNULL to SQL statement. This fixes the problem but is not a practical solution in our opinion for productive environments.

At the moment: Out of any idea. The code shown above works fine from a XAMPP on Windows XP and Windos 7 with no errors. It is not relevant if we use PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS. Both possible options work fine an the result array is shown as expected

Are there any solutions for this problem? Thanks for any help and ideas.

Addtional information:
We use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. Is it possible that this error occures due to an error in libc 64bit? Seems that the script aborts "somewhere there".

Answer (score 2):

Ok. After some hours testing and setting up additional development environments we found out, that this is an issue on 64bit systems.

The system expect an strict 8-byte field length within the answer (fetchAll-function), but got a 4-byte field length. This causes the segfault mentioned above.

Setting up a nearly identically 32bit environment was the (temporary) solution. The script is working now. Also the attribute PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS works as expected.

For a production environment this means a RAM limitation to 4 GB :/

Comment: Similar: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927983/segfault-with-unixodbc-db2-php-centos

Comment: Did you mean 8-byte & 4-byte?

Comment: Same on RHEL: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/64-bit-odbc-driver-problem-beetween-rhel-and-as400-iseries-huge-memory-php-pdo-4175454060